# Android go back to main activity and get intent data

Tags: android, android-intent

I am in an activity started from my main activity, I'm returning to that the main activity but with some data in the intent. Where does my main activity return to so I can fetch the data?

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBetsWindow.class);
            intent.putExtra("BetName", betName);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start Activity with request code in **MainActivity.java**.

```
     Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
     startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

you can get data from **SecondActivity** in this way.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        System.out.println("REQUEST CODE:" + requestCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String return data = data.getStringExtra("value");
                // now you can used this data in this activity which is come in secondActivity
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now **SecondActivity.java** you have to passdata to **MainActivity.java** file in this way
for example in save button click you have to pass all this data.

```
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.putExtra("value",et.getText().toString());
       setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: Will setResult() destroy the activity as well? As in do the same thing as this

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: After setResult(); you have to call finish();

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`startActivityForResult` in your main activity and process the result in `onActivityResult`() method. in MyBetsWindow use `setResult` to return the result before it finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do the following in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
     super.onCreate(bundle);
     ...
     Intent current = getIntent();
     String betName = current.getStringExtra("BetName");
     ...
}
```

If the only purpose you have is going to another activity and collecting some data, for returning to the MainActivity then @Bolton answer is more appropiate.

Good Luck